# Running angular app without server - By double clicking the html file

Tags: angularjs

I have developed an Angular assignment using  `$http.get` service calls to get JSON data, `routing($routeProvider)` among other features.

The problem is that the assignee (the person checking my assignment) does not have Node.js or server installed to run the app on their end.

Is there any work around for this issue so that assignee can make this work on his end?
Can I make an executable batch file like we do with `Java` programs?

Otherwise what features of Angular do I need to change, to make the application independent?

Comment: Depends a lot on your setup. Angular in itself does not require a server.

Comment: angular does not require a server, but some of the modules (notably angular-route and $http) do.  also, `$.getJSON` isn't angular.

Comment: FWIW, why would someone assign you a job that they have no way of verifying, assuming you are performing the job to their specifications?

Comment: It was my choice to develop the app using angular. Unfortunately I did not take into account the setup required.